# How to create a Flowable that completes as soon as its last subscriber cancels its subscription

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have a case where I need to establish a reactive stream composed of multiple elements that can be completed in two different ways.

The chain that I have looks a bit like this:

At the top of the chain, I have multiple `Flowable` producers that each regularly poll different remote resources and emit messages when they get new results.

Each of these producers, have a single intermediate subscriber that further transforms the messages.

In turn, all of these intermediate subscribers have the same root subscriber that merges the transformed events from everyone into a single `Flowable`

What I would like is to be able to cancel any of the subscriptions of the root subscriber, and have that un-subscription event basically cause the un-subscribee (is that a word?) to complete.

In other words, I want my polling process to stop if nobody is listening. If I ever need to restart the polling, I just rebuild a new chain.

Are there any RxJava operators that allow me to create this kind of relationship between a producer and a subscriber? And if not, what would be the easiest way to do so?

I have a sort of solution right now, but it doesn't feel like a very good solution and requires lots of boilerplate code for each element in the chain. It looks a bit like that:

```
private class AutoUnsubscribing {
    private final AtomicReference<Subscription> upstreamSubscription = new AtomicReference<>(null);
    private final PublishProcessor<LedgerEvent> publisher = PublishProcessor.create();

    public Flowable<LedgerEvent> getFlowable(Flowable<LedgerEvent> upstream) {
        upstream.subscribe(new Subscriber<LedgerEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
                upstreamSubscription.set(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(LedgerEvent ledgerEvent) {
                publisher.onNext(ledgerEvent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                publisher.onError(t);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                publisher.onComplete();
            }
        });

        return publisher.doOnCancel(() -> {
            if (!publisher.hasSubscribers()) {
                // no more subscribers. unsubscribe from upstream and complete this stream
                upstreamSubscription.get().cancel();
                upstreamSubscription.set(null);
                publisher.onComplete();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But there must be a better solution than that.

Comment: See [`share()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/).

Comment: That doesn't really match what I want. I want the publisher to complete when it has no more subscribers. That doesn't seem to have anything to do with what `share()` does, or am I missing something?

Comment: Also note that the producers at the top of the chain are all hot, so wouldn't `share()` be un-necessary in this case?

Comment: Makes no sense. You said you recreate the flow for a new run so nobody would ever see a completed source, right? Or do you want latecommers to observe `onComplete` until you decide it is okay to restart the sequence?

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. It makes no sense to have the publisher complete because nobody is listening anyway. And if I have a chain of flowables wher all elements need to implement that behavior, each element in the chain needs to unsubscribe from their upstream once they lose their own last subscriber right? (otherwise the publisher at the top of the chain will still assume somebody is listening). Is there an operator to do that?

Comment: Your description still matches share(). Cancellation is propagated in a graph of subscriptions automatically for you. Please provide an example of your complicated flow in the unlikely case you do something that requires extra considerations.

Comment: "Cancellation is propagated in a graph of subscriptions automatically for you." That must be the bit that I didn't understand. So in general, when a subscriber cancels its subscription to a Flowable, and that subscriber was the last one, the flowable will also automatically cancel its own subscription to it own upstream Publisher?

Comment: A refCounted connectable source does that. Cold observables serve consumers individually, so they have no effect on one another.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I've gained a bit more experience with RxJava, I am able to formulate an answer to my question. Basically, the chain that we have is the following:

```
+----------+      +-------------+      +----------+
| consumer |←-----| transformer |←-----| producer |
+----------+      +-------------+      +----------+
```

What was really needed was a way to make `transformer` cancellable, in such a way that when it is cancelled, its subscription to `producer` was cancelled (so `producer` could do some cleanup before terminating itself), AND `transformer` completed itself (so that `consumer` would become  aware of that).

The best solution I could find was to implement a `detachable` operator like so:

```
public static <T> FlowableTransformer<T, T> detachable(
            Consumer<Disposable> disposableConsumer) {
    PublishProcessor<Object> stopper = PublishProcessor.create();
    Disposable disposable = new Disposable() {
        private AtomicBoolean disposed = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        @Override
        public void dispose() {
            if (disposed.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                stopper.onNext(new Object());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isDisposed() {
            return disposed.get();
        }
    };

    return upstream -> upstream.takeUntil(stopper)
            .doOnSubscribe(s -> disposableConsumer.accept(disposable));

}
```

Which can then be used that way:

```
AtomicReference<Disposable> transformerDisposable = new AtomicReference<>();

producer
    .compose(detachable(transformerDisposable::set))
    .subscriber(consumer)
```

Then `transfomer` can be cancelled at will using

```
transformerDisposable.dispose()
```

Which will indeed cause `producer` to call it own `onUnsubscribe`, and `consumer` to receive an `onComplete` notification.